# Problems with xdebug and CentOS

Tags: php, linux, eclipse, centos, xdebug

I'm trying to install xdebug and I'm getting the following error message on eclipse:

> launching: waiting for xdebug Session

and it stop loading at 57%.

With NetBeans I get:

> waiting for xdebug Session

So I think the problem is with xdebug configure on CentOS

my `php.ini` configuration:

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so 
[debug]
; Remote settings
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

`phpinfo()` shows the xdebug installed.
My centOS version is 6.2.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you make a remote debug log (see http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log), what does it say? Which ports is netbeans/eclipse listening too? (netstat -a -n | grep LISTEN | grep tcp)?

Comment: the problem was with port. i repareid with "setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1" thanks anyway.

Comment: Just to satisfy my curiosity, what did the remote_log say?

Comment: Thank you user1333540 for reporting what fixed it.  I just had the same issue on CentOS 6.4 and I would *never* have thought to even look at SELinux settings - I didn't even know what 'setsebool' was until I read your answer.  Thank you so much for reporting back, you possibly just saved my job.

Answer (score 2):

I just setup NetBeans 7.2.1 and xdebug 2.1.4 on my Centos 6.3 machine and was getting the "waiting for xdebug session" message in NetBeans.  After messing with the php settings and confirming xdebug was correct in phpinfo() for hours to no avail, the solution for me was to set a default browser in NetBeans... Tools->Options->Web Browser.  Setting this to Firefox solved it! Hope this helps someone else...